# Swagger Response Messages using Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, swagger, swagger-ui

views.py:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from rest_framework import schemas
from rest_framework import status, response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, renderer_classes
from rest_framework_swagger.renderers import OpenAPIRenderer, SwaggerUIRenderer

from DjangoProject.settings import db
from DjangoProjectApp.serializers import RestaurantsSerializer


@api_view()
@renderer_classes([OpenAPIRenderer, SwaggerUIRenderer])
def schema_view(request):
    generator = schemas.SchemaGenerator(title='Restaurant API')
    return response.Response(generator.get_schema(request=request))


@api_view(['GET'])
def restaurant_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        restaurantCollection = db.Restaurant
        restaurantlist = []
        for s in restaurantCollection.find():
            restaurantlist.append(s)
        serializer = RestaurantsSerializer(restaurantlist, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, safe=False)
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models


class Restaurant(models.Model):
    _id = models.TextField()
    name = models.TextField()
    rating = models.IntegerField()
```

serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from DjangoProjectApp.models import Restaurant


class RestaurantsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Restaurant
        fields = ('_id', 'name', 'rating')
```

Now, how I can show the Response Messages in Swagger using Django.

In Response Messages there is only 200 is showing as Response Code.

I need to show the responses for different Status Codes. I need the full description for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey Avijit, have you found an answer for this already? I also need the same functionality.

Comment: No, Have you got it?  Erika?

Comment: Hey Avijit, I got an answer from someone in another thread, maybe it can be useful to you too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40175410/how-to-generate-list-of-response-messages-in-django-rest-swagger/40932691#answer-40932691

Comment: @AvijitKarmakar Hi AVijit  do you get it working