# How to fill response schema in Django REST Swagger?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger

In Django 1.11, I want to fill in this section (it's a rest_framework_swagger interface https://marcgibbons.com/django-rest-swagger/#quick-start):

[image]

Now it's empty and seems like it's not parsed out of comments. I don't see in the docs how to add it for this version of Django.

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/40932691/2314347

Comment: are you using any 3rd party packages? or bare DRF?

Comment: @JPG rest_framework_swagger